# Dividir linha par por linha ímpar ao longo das colunas

Tags: r, loop, apply

Preciso dividir as linhas pares pelas linhas impares ao longo das colunas em um dataframe do R

Segue um MVP

```
# Nomes das colunas
colunas <- c("RMSE","MAE","MAPE","MASE")

# Dados
mz <- matrix(runif(40), nrow = 10, ncol = 4)
colnames(mz) <- colunas

# Para uma coluna o código roda bem
treino_teste <- numeric(10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  treino_teste[i] <- mz[2*i, "RMSE"]/mz[i, "RMSE"]
}

# Resultado para uma coluna
res <- treino_teste %>% cbind(colunas)

# Código com problema:
for (j in 1:4) {
  for (i in 1:10) {
    treino_teste[i,j] <- mz[2*i,j]/mz[i,j]
  }
}
```

Ao tentar fazer as iteraçoes para todas as colunas e gravar em uma matriz recebo um erro:
*Error in treino_teste[i, j] <- mz[2 * i, j]/mz[i, j] :*
*incorrect number of subscripts on matrix*

Algúem teria alguma solução com o looping ou talvez mais elegante com a família apply?

Answer (score 4):

Defina uma função que resolva o problema para uma coluna genérica e aplique essa função a cada coluna da matriz.

```r
# resultados reprodutíveis
set.seed(2023)
# Nomes das colunas
colunas <- c("RMSE","MAE","MAPE","MASE")

# Dados
mz <- matrix(runif(40), nrow = 10, ncol = 4)
colnames(mz) <- colunas

faux <- function(x) {
  sapply(seq.int(length(x)/2L), \(i) x[2*i]/x[2*i - 1])
}

apply(mz, 2, faux)
#>           RMSE       MAE      MAPE      MASE
#> [1,] 0.7183475 0.1726491 0.6975585 0.8759951
#> [2,] 2.4329072 5.5382856 2.7452295 0.6335880
#> [3,] 3.9775579 0.1694690 0.8848418 1.0387234
#> [4,] 1.4498068 2.5797582 0.1493072 0.8480003
#> [5,] 1.8096844 2.2167254 0.3604911 1.2431108
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Numa só linha, com uma função anónima:

```r
apply(mz, 2, \(x) sapply(seq.int(length(x)/2L), \(i) x[2*i]/x[2*i - 1]))
#>           RMSE       MAE      MAPE      MASE
#> [1,] 0.7183475 0.1726491 0.6975585 0.8759951
#> [2,] 2.4329072 5.5382856 2.7452295 0.6335880
#> [3,] 3.9775579 0.1694690 0.8848418 1.0387234
#> [4,] 1.4498068 2.5797582 0.1493072 0.8480003
#> [5,] 1.8096844 2.2167254 0.3604911 1.2431108
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Pode simplesmente usar indexação, usando um vetor lógico de comprimento 2 para selecionar linhas alternadas. Por exemplo:

```
# Dados
set.seed(2023)
mz <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(40), 10, 4, dimnames = list(NULL, c("RMSE","MAE","MAPE","MASE"))))

# Linhas pares
mz[c(FALSE, TRUE), ]
#>         RMSE       MAE       MAPE      MASE
#> 2  0.3351910 0.1488786 0.43817257 0.6635921
#> 4  0.3961200 0.9992733 0.93309259 0.4589465
#> 6  0.1208849 0.1426491 0.63085187 0.7005136
#> 8  0.6178579 0.8896255 0.11145029 0.6911815
#> 10 0.4763239 0.7090158 0.09851809 0.8905799
```

Assim, para dividir todas as linhas pares pelas ímpares:

```
mz[c(FALSE, TRUE), ]/mz[c(TRUE, FALSE), ]
#>         RMSE       MAE      MAPE      MASE
#> 2  0.7183475 0.1726491 0.6975585 0.8759951
#> 4  2.4329072 5.5382856 2.7452295 0.6335880
#> 6  3.9775579 0.1694690 0.8848418 1.0387234
#> 8  1.4498068 2.5797582 0.1493072 0.8480003
#> 10 1.8096844 2.2167254 0.3604911 1.2431108
```